# Extract contents from the url using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract contents from a url and this is the below content that I want to extract using jsoup.

```
 And I want to extract text of <div id =content>

    <div id="content">
                  <!-- Start: Header -->
<div id="content-group_header-0" class="header content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-0-0 first-pod">

    <h4 class="h4 no-font-replace ">
    Your imagination knows no borders or boundaries.  </h4>


  </div>
<!-- End: Header -->

<!-- Start: Open HTML -->
<div id="content-group_open_html-0" class="open-html wysiwyg content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-0-0">

  <div class="open-html"><p>And we say, let it run wild. Because in that freedom is the shape of what’s to come.</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Whatever it is you do, our pathway to innovation begins and ends with you.</p>
</div>
  </div>

<!-- End: Open HTML -->
<!-- Start: Header -->
<div id="content-group_header-1" class="header content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-1-1">

    <h4 class="h4 no-font-replace ">
    Dreams grow, but not without nurturing.  </h4>

  </div>
<!-- End: Header -->

<!-- Start: Open HTML -->
<div id="content-group_open_html-1" class="open-html wysiwyg content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-1-1">

  <p>In our fiscal year 2010, we invested 23% of our gross revenue or $2.549 billion in R&D—an investment that has increased every year since 2000. It’s how we’ve been able to stay ahead of the curve and deliver on the promise of new wireless technologies:</p>

<ul class="supporting-content">
<li> Hello World</li>

<li>We were the first to produce a single</li>

<li>We were the first to commercialize a chipset</li>

<li>We were the first to deliver GHz processing power integrated with 3G</li>

<li>We are the first to produce a laptop solution</li>

<li>We are the first to commercialize</li>

</ul>
<p>In fact, with a current intellectual property portfolio consisting of more than 77,000 patents granted and pending</p>
  </div>
<!-- End: Open HTML -->
<!-- Start: Header -->
<div id="content-group_header-2" class="header content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-2-2">

    <h4 class="h4 no-font-replace ">
    Our partnerships are our most valuable assets.  </h4>

  </div>
<!-- End: Header -->

<!-- Start: Open HTML -->
<div id="content-group_open_html-2" class="open-html wysiwyg content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-2-2">

<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

  </div>
<!-- End: Open HTML -->
<!-- Start: Header -->
<div id="content-group_header-3" class="header content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-3-3">

    <h4 class="h4 no-font-replace ">
    So where does the pathway to innovation lead?  </h4>

  </div>
<!-- End: Header -->

<!-- Start: Open HTML -->
<div id="content-group_open_html-3" class="open-html wysiwyg content-podgroup-wrapper content-podgroup-3-3 last-pod">

  <div class="open-html"><p>We’re eager to find out ourselves, because if the pathway begins with you, then it’s up to you to decide where it’s headed. So let’s explore the possibilities. Let’s never stop discovering.</p>
<p>Working together, the pathway to innovation can go as far as our dreams will take us.</p>
</div>
  </div>
<!-- End: Open HTML -->
                </div><!-- END: content -->
```

Can anybody explain how it can be done using JSOUP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you use regular expressions for this? Jsoup is a HTML parser which eats [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) only. Just use a proper CSS selector. I understand that you want to select `<div id="content">`? Use the CSS ID-selector of this format `#id` for this.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.host.com/domain").get();
Element content = document.select("#content").first();
System.out.println(content.html()); 
// ...
```

Or if you want to get the text only, use `Element#text()` instead of `Element#html()`:

```
System.out.println(content.text()); 
// ...
```

Read the following documents thoroughly to learn how to use CSS selectors in Jsoup:

- [Jsoup cookbook - Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

[You shouldn't think about using regexps to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I have tried this way.. But by this way I get html tags also after the <div id= content> like h4 etc etc. I want only the text if you see the above link that we are scrapping. I want this whole text `Your imagination knows no borders or boundaries.

And we say, let it run wild. Because in that freedom is the shape of what’s to come.   cont'd`